R markdown and readline()
I am attempting to create a vignette in R Markdown for a package that I have created. Within one of these R functions, it has a readline() requiring user input to confirm continuing an analysis based on certain thresholds. This works in the terminal, as the user can simply answer the question. However, for an R Markdown it automatically spits out a warning. Is there a way to get around this functionality, or to prespecify the user response, or is this not a possibility within R markdown?
I have no issues running in the console, but this will not knit in R markdown. The function asks the user whether to continue and prompts a Yes(1) or No(2) answer. If no, the function stops and prints a warning. If yes, the function continues on. In R Markdown, it automatically spits out the warning.


For this (and other) reasons it’s generally a bad idea to accept input inside a function directly from the user. It’s almost always better to use function arguments, and to let the caller of the function take care of the input from the user.

From ?readline:

In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and the value is "".

So one idea would be to couple interactive() with ui == "" to try to determine if one is running the vignette:
if (TRUE) {
  repeat{
    ui = readline("Strong evidence... ")
    
    in_vignette <- !interactive() && ui == ""
    
    if (ui == 2)
      stop("User is...")
    else if (ui == 1 || in_vignette) {
      cat("Continuing analysis...")
      return()
    }
    else
      cat("Invalid input...")
  }
}
#> Strong evidence... 
#> Continuing analysis...

Created on 2024-09-05 with reprex v2.1.1

Thank you for this response. It does not appear to be working, though. I am currently trying to find or create a function that can identify if the code is being run in an R markdown document and then use an ifelse set of statements to determine the value of ui. I have not had success yet, though.
